# Use function parametr in chain call - javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs, redux

Hey guys so I have a function

```
export function handleShowData(value, param1, param2) {
  const mergeData = value.map(value => {
    return [
      value.time * 1000,
      Math.round((value.param1 + value.param2) / 2 * 100 / 100)
    ];
  });
  debugger;

  const points = mergeData;
  const series = new TimeSeries({
    name: "Series",
    columns: ["time", "value"],
    points
  });

  return {
    type: HANDLE_SHOW_RESULTS,
    payload: series
  };
}
```

and I need to pass the param1 and param2 into value chain to get the variable that I want. If I hardcode param1 and param2 i get what I need but I need it to be reusable. Both param1 and 2 are strings.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass them as param1 and param2, 
you can access them as:

```
Math.round((value[param1]+ value[param2]) / 2 * 100 / 100)
```

Using the square bracket notation, you can access the object keys as variables.

The dot notation would not allow this.

`value.param1` would not exist.

Comment: I knew it was something elemental. Thanks :)